# How to sendKeys wherever the cursor is in selenium nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, selenium

I have created a script to comment in facebook posts, I did clicked on comment box, and cursor do appears but unable to perform `.sendKeys()`

here's my code:

```
var commentBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="addComment_'+this.postIdSlice+'"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div'));
actions.mouseMove(commentBox).click().perform();
driver.sleep(2000);
actions.sendKeys("Hello").perform();
```

but when I execute it doesnt sends 'Hello' to comment box. 
PS: that postIdSlice is id of the post, no issues there just want to push/send string in that commentbox.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to interact with their website in any automated way. You have to use the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Xpath to click on the comment box, then you can use the ActionSequence to sequnce input and ENTER key.

```
let action = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver);
    action.sendKeys("comment");
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

action.perform()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was doing mistake and was using .actions from driver. not webdriver.